# Delete characters from beginning of block in Draft.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, markdown, draftjs

I'm trying to use [Draft.js](https://draftjs.org) to make a rich text editor that allows the user to use a subset of Markdown syntax (just headers and blockquotes).

I can get the Editor to set the type of the block to `blockquote` and apply the appropriate `className` and style, but now I can't figure out how to delete the syntactic sugar from the block.

Here is my code.

```
function handleChange(editorState) {
  const rawObject = convertToRaw(editorState.getCurrentContent());

  // Allow for Markdown editing in Draft.js
  rawObject.blocks.forEach((block) => {
    // If block starts with ">", then convert it to a blockquote
    if (block.text.slice(0, 1) === ">") {
      console.log(editorState.getSelection());
      let blockquote = Modifier.setBlockType(
        editorState.getCurrentContent(),
        editorState.getSelection(),
        "blockquote"
      );
      let state = EditorState.push(editorState, blockquote, "apply-block-type");

      // Effectively sets the block to type "blockquote", applying styles
      // Now, how do I delete the ">"?

      seteditorState(state);
    }
  });
}

function myBlockStyleFn(contentBlock) {
  const type = contentBlock.getType();
  let className;
  switch (type) {
    // ...
    case "blockquote": {
      className = "blockquote";
    }
    default: {
      break;
    }
  }
  return className;
}

return (
  <Editor
    customStyleMap={styleMap}
    blockRenderMap={extendedBlockRenderMap}
    editorState={editorState}
    onChange={handleChange}
    handleKeyCommand={handleKeyCommand}
    blockStyleFn={myBlockStyleFn}
  />
);
```

I've tried using...

```
block.text = block.text.slice(1);
```

... but the Editor state is an immutable object that can only be updated with functions.

> Update: This seems to work if I force the editor to select all text inside of the block.

```
let replacement = Modifier.replaceText(
  state.getCurrentContent(),
  state.getSelection(),
  block.text.slice(1)
);

state = EditorState.push(state, replacement);
```

... but this removes the first `Modifier` and exhibits strange behavior, such as inserting characters from the selection back into itself.

Update: I'm able to achieve the desired results by selecting the content from inside of the block after issuing the syntactic sugar. It seems that the issue is with passing `state.getSelection()` into the replacement modifier. I only want to select the current block but it seems that nothing is getting selected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `merge` with `anchorOffset` and `focusOffset` on a `selectionState`, then push the new `Modifier` onto the state and set it.

```
var selectionState = editorState.getSelection();

let blockquote = Modifier.setBlockType(
  editorState.getCurrentContent(),
  selectionState,
  "blockquote"
);

let state = EditorState.push(editorState, blockquote);

// Update: This seems to work if I force the editor to select all text inside of the block
let replacement = Modifier.replaceText(
  state.getCurrentContent(),
  selectionState.merge({
    anchorOffset: 0,
    focusOffset: block.text.length
  }),
  block.text.slice(1)
);

state = EditorState.push(state, replacement);

seteditorState(state);
```